# HTML5 video JS onclick play/pause/play from beginning

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a local video file to play using html5 and js.  I'd like the user to click on the video image to play, then next click pause, but then third click would play again from the beginning. Am JS novice, but found this great code to be able to do inline except it restarts from the current pointer.  Is there a way to use a similar statement to have the video restart from the beginning after pause without a load, etc. using similar conditional code? Have not seen exactly what I want without more extensive script...maybe that is necessary?

```
<video controlsList="nodownload nofullscreen" 
        onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();">
        <source src="img/white_noise.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Some failure message
</video>
```

Comment: I should mention I can achieve the result I want by using: onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : (this.pause(),this.load());" , but I did want to avoid the "load" if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...will leave in case it helps anyone else:

```
onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : (this.pause(),this.currentTime=0);"
```